# Making a class append data to a textbox on a form

Tags: c#, class

Basically I have a class that handles some websocket things and when a message is received the class code you see below is fired. The messagebox fires fine and shows the data but the text isn't entered into the textbox and it just seems to crash with no error.

Form Code:

```
CreateSocket cs = new CreateSocket();
cs.Form = this;

public void AddMessage(string Msg)
{
    TxtMessageList.Text += Msg + Environment.NewLine;
}
```

Class Code:

```
public FrmMain Form;
Form.AddMessage(Json.Message.Sender.Username + ": " + Json.Message.Message);
```

Comment: Can you show us how this class is called? I have a suspicion you're creating a new instance of the form and not using an existing one.

Comment: How the class is called? Do you mean the form method. If so, that's already there and It appears I am creating a new instance. But the only way I know to call a method on a form is by making it static and then I can't add text to the textbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to just make a bit of an assumption that you're not passing in an existing instance of a form to your class.

You need to do this:

```
class YourAppenderClass {
    private FrmMain _form;

    public YourAppenderClass(FrmMain form) {
        _form = form;
    }

    public void AddMessage(string msg) {
        _form.TxtMessageList.Text += msg + Environment.NewLine;
    }
}
```

You pass an existing instance (`this`) to your class. You use that instance to do what you need.

..and call it like so:

```
YourAppenderClass appender = new YourAppenderClass(this); // "this" is your main form
appender.AddMessage("Blah");
```

Or, you could instead use the existing instance to call the non-static method you supplied:

```
// somewhere in the class..
_form.AddMessage("Blah"); // _form works because it is the instance you passed in
```

Comment: I couldn't really understand what you put so I did this in the class:
public FrmMain Form;
Then did this when I created the instance of the class:
class.Form = this;

But now it just crashes with no error?

Comment: I updated it to include the way you're doing it at the bottom.

Comment: Fixed it now, It was the way I was doing something. Thanks you helped me fix the class thing!